# Filtering GALERY with Multiple Selection Tags Filter in WIX

Tags: javascript, html, velo

I planning to have a big database/collection of images in Wix Gallery.
I want to filter them out by using numerous tags to find a very specific image in the gallery due to user needs.

As for now, I manage to adjust the filter for just one category working.
My website: [My Galery](https://www.tocidesign.tk/imvurooms)
Code example:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {

    $w('#roomcategory').onChange(() => {
        const selectedTag = $w('#roomcategory').value;

        let filter = wixData.filter();

        if (selectedTag.length > 0) {
            filter = filter.hasSome("roomcategory", selectedTag);
        }

        $w('#portfolioDataset').setFilter(filter);

    })
});

/**
*   Adds an event handler that runs when the element is clicked.
    [Read more](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.ClickableMixin.html#onClick)
*    @param {$w.MouseEvent} event
*/
export function roomcategory_click(event) {
    // This function was added from the Properties & Events panel. To learn more, visit http://wix.to/UcBnC-4
    // Add your code for this event here: 
}

/**
*   Adds an event handler that runs when an input element's value
 is changed.
    [Read more](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.ValueMixin.html#onChange)
*    @param {$w.Event} event
*/
export function roomcategory_change(event) {
    // This function was added from the Properties & Events panel. To learn more, visit http://wix.to/UcBnC-4
    // Add your code for this event here: 
}
```

[Layout of tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpWOu.png)

There's a video on YT I followed by this guy filtering Repeater not a gallery.
[video link : Multiple Selection Tags Filter in WIX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAFF-6_OkwY&ab_channel=TheWIXClub)

I tried to edit his code as well but doesn't work for me.

```
    import wixData from 'wix-data';
​
$w.onReady(function () {
 
    $w("#roomcategory, #capacity, #roomrating, #colortag, #languagetag").onChange(function () {
        search();
    }
 
    (function search() {
 
        let filter = wixData.filter();
 
        let roomcategoryIdx = $w("#roomcategory").selectedIndices;
        let capacityIdx = $w("#capacity").selectedIndices;
        let roomratingIdx = $w("#roomrating").selectedIndices;
        let colortagIdx = $w("#colortag").selectedIndices;
        let languagetagIdx = $w("#languagetag").selectedIndices;
        
        let roomcategoryVal = $w("#roomcategory").value;
        let capacityVal = $w("#capacity").value;
        let roomratingVal = $w("#roomrating").value;
        let colortagVal = $w("#colortag").value;
        let languagetagVal = $w("#languagetag").value;
        
        if (roomcategoryIdx.length > 0 || capacityIdx.length > 0 || roomratingIdx.length > 0) || colortagIdx.length > 0) || languagetagIdx.length > 0) {
 
            filter = filter.hasAll("roomcategory", roomcategorysVal)
                .and(filter = filter.hasAll("capacity", capacityVal))
                .and(filter = filter.hasAll("roomrating", roomratingVal))
                .and(filter = filter.hasAll("colortag", colortagVal))
                .and(filter = filter.hasAll("languagetag", languagetagVal))
            $w("#portfolioDataset").setFilter(filter)
                .then(count)
 
        } else {
            $w("#portfolioDataset").setFilter(filter)
                .then(count)
        }
 
        $w("#resetfilters").onClick(function () {
            $w("#roomcategory, #capacity, #roomrating, #colortag, #languagetag").value = undefined;
            $w("#portfolioDataset").setFilter(wixData.filter()).then(count);
        });
 
    }
 
    //COUNT ITEM
    function count() {
        let count = $w("#portfolioDataset").getTotalCount();
        if (count > 0) {
            $w("#countText").text = `${count} rooms found`;
        } else { $w("#countText").text = `No rooms found`; }
 
        return count;
    }
 
    $w("#portfolioDataset").onReady(function () {
        count();
    });
});
```

Comment: changed tags from "wix" to "velo", hopefully this will bring you more answers. WIX on stackoverflow is something different.